# How to disable simplemde in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, simplemde

I have a requirement where the markdown should be in read only mode and text entry should be restricted.

[disabled]="true" does not seem to work when using simplemde.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simplemde/v/1.3.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that simplemde doesn't support disable option so i suggest you to replace it with CkEditor which has disable options and more options as well 
you can follow instructions listed here to get it worked https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: @AhmedAbdelfattah Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelfattah can you suggest a way to render simplemde content in angular?